# How do I use ljust and rjust correctly in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string

I have some code:

```
line_width = 26

ch3 = "Chapter 3: Letters page 13"
puts(ch3.ljust(line_width/2) + ch3.rjust(line_width/2))

#=> Chapter 3: Letters page 13Chapter 3: Letters page 13
```

I would like the output to be split down the middle like this:

```
Half-Text__________________________________________________Half-Text
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Do you actually want a line where you show one between the two "Half-Text" strings, or is that to represent spaces? What do you mean by "Half-Text"? Why not replace "Half-Text" with whatever you actually want there for your example. I assume `line_width` equal the length of the string beginning `"Chapter 3: Letters"` and ending `"page 13"`, with a line or spaces between. If so, there's only one space (or a line of length one) between the two ends. If it were page `"101"`, there would be no space between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split the text into two first.

```
line_width = 26

ch3 = "Chapter 3: Letters page 13"

ch3 = ch3.split(/\s(?=page)/) #=> ["Chapter 3: Letters", "page 13"]

puts(ch3[0].ljust(line_width / 2) + ch3[1].rjust(line_width / 2))
```

This outputs

```
Chapter 3: Letters      page 13
```

Comment: Ahh thank you. I was just reading my text book and it never mentioned using split. Very strange. Glad it wasn't just me being a dumb human.

Comment: `"Chapter 3: Letters".size #=>  18` and `line_width/2 #=> 13`, so `puts(ch3[0].ljust(line_width / 2)` tries to stuff a string of length `18` into `13` spaces. The result is that `.ljust(line_width / 2)` is disregarded. (For example,  `"abcdef".ljust(1) #=> "abcdef"`). However, since `"page 13".size #=> 7`, `ch3[1]` will be padded to the left with `13-7 #=> 6` spaces. As a result your actual line length is  `18 + 6 + 7 #=> 31` spaces, not `26` spaces.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, I wouldn't use `ljust` and `rjust` here.

```
line_width = 40
ch3 = "Chapter 3: Letters page 13"

left, right = ch3.split(/\s(?=page\s+\d+)/)
  #=> ["Chapter 3: Letters", "page 13"] 
puts left + ' '*(line_width-left.size-right.size) + right
```

prints

```
Chapter 3: Letters               page 13
```

Note that `' '*(line_width-left.size-right.size)` creates a string comprised of

```
line_with-left.size-right.size
  #=> 40 - 18 - 7 => 15
```

spaces.